# RHEL 5 patches issue

Tags: redhat

I would like to know the risk of having an older update still being present, while a newer one is already working?

Can the vulnerabilities from the old kernel be exploited when a more recent kernel has been installed?

Comment: That system is currently on paid-for extended lifecycle support, yes?